# Retrieve data from two different table in a single report

Tags: sql

I have two table Employee and Salary table, salary consists Salary of employee in a field named Salary_employee.
Second one is Extra Expense, Extra expense consists records related to extra expenses of a company like electricity bills,office maintenance in a field named extra_expense.

(Their is no relationship between these two table).

Finally, I just wanted to show all the expenses of company in a report, for this i need to group both the table. what to use here join or union ??.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no relationship between the two tables, then this really cannot work since you dont know where the expense is supposed to tie into. You should redesign the database if possible as this sounds impossible based on your description.

**UPDATE**

OK, by the look of your screenshots, I am guessing that this database only stores one companies info? And not multiple?

IF that is correct, AND if all you want to do is squish the data together into one flowing report of expenses, then I would indeed suggest a `UNION`. A `JOIN` would not give you the flow you are looking for. A `UNION` will just smash the two outputs together into one...which I think is what you are asking for?

```
SELECT ext_amount AS amount, ext_date AS date_of_trans
FROM extra_expenses
UNION
SELECT sal_cash AS amount, sal_dateof_payment AS date_of_trans
FROM employee_salary
```

Comment: Hey justin i have uploaded screen shot of it, have a look thanks

Comment: @San updated my answer. If my assumption is correct, then a UNION should be fine. I am so used to databases holding more than one companies info that I had assumed you would need a company identifier

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't need to use group *or* join. Simply query both tables separately within a script and handle them both accordingly to their structure to produce a report.

Join and union are functions which you can use to extract different information on a common thing from separate tables. E.g. if you have a user whose private details are stored in one table, but their profile information is in another table. If you want to display both private details as well as profile info, you can join the two tables by the common user name in order to combine and gather all info on the user in one query.